# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip

I'm trying to install pandas via `pip install pandas` on my laptop.

Environment:

- Window 11 Pro
- Python 3.10.4
- Pip version 22.0.4

Compatibility:

- [Officially Python 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html#python-version-support)
- [You must have pip>=19.3 to install from PyPI.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html#installing-from-pypi)

```
C:\Users\PC>pip install pandas
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages)
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.4.2.tar.gz (4.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Collecting pytz>=2020.1
  Using cached pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2010 lines of output]
      C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-q3kdt5nb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:459: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
```

> ...

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

What I have tried:

- updated pip to 22.1.1
- installed wheel 0.37.1
- uninstalled and installed pip
- uninstalled and installed python 3.10.4

---

Error still reproducible with [pandas 1.5.1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v1.5.1)

---

**Thanks to @[AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) which has pointed up that there is no and may will no 32-bit version of pandas in the future. [See the discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44453).**

Comment: try `pip install manager` then `*pip install pandas*` - [where I found this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/96580/question-about-installing-pandas-in-python.html)

Comment: @PrestigeDev thanks for your advise, but I ran into a different error to install this package `error: metadata-generation-failed`. Im trying to install scipy now. If I have similar issues I'll try to reinstall python.

Comment: I would use Anaconda if that doesn't work

Comment: "The easiest way to install pandas is to install it as part of the Anaconda distribution, a cross platform distribution for data analysis and scientific computing." - [pandas - Installation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html)

Comment: @PrestigeDev I do not like the idea of being forced to use anaconda for pandas. If there was not a regular way with PyPi I would agree and its a normal condition, but since it does not explicitly state it is necessary I would like to have it work. :D But thank you for your time and effort to solve my issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pandas doesn't require Anaconda to work, but based on `python310-32` in your output, you're using a 32-bit build of Python.

Pandas [evidently](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.5.1/#files) does not ship 32-bit wheels for Python 3.10 (they do have win32 wheels for Python 3.8 and Python 3.9 though). (There could be alternate sources for pre-built 32-bit wheels, such as [Gohlke's site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas).)

In other words, on that platform you would need to install Pandas from source, which will likely be a rather difficult undertaking, and can't be done directly within `pip` anyway (as you noticed via `error: metadata-generation-failed`).

If your system is capable of running 64-bit Python, you should switch to it.

Comment: First of all, thanks for clearing this up. Could you please elaborate why I shouldn't wait for a 32-bit wheel, rather than switching to 64-bit python? As far as I know it is just important for extensive memory usage.

Comment: I don't think there will be a 32-bit wheel (it would have been uploaded along with the other wheels), so you'd wait for a long time.

Comment: [They seem to hesitate with it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44453)

Comment: :shrug: Well, judging by the timestamps on that issue you'll _still_ be waiting for a long time for them to finish hesitating.

Comment: lmao, yes. I'm not in hurry. Though, I will need it in the future again.

Comment: It would be easier to just go with 64-bit Python. Is there a reason for you to stick with 32-bit?

Comment: No particular, no. But I remember some other technologies I have used in the past wasn't available in 64-bit. That's why I had switched from 64-bit to 32-bit in the first place. I rather thought about starting to use virtual environments so I will be more flexible in the future and maintain both for my projects.

Comment: You should _always_ use virtualenvs-per-project anyway. I would still recommend switching over to 64-bit – if there are things that don't work in 64-bit, shame on them...

Comment: I have 64-bit Python and am facing the same problem as OP.

Answer (score 5):

Install pandas in Python 3.10

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Step one

[Download pandas wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#_pandas),
Choose one that suits your operating system

#### Step two

install the wheel from absolute path

```
pip install pandas-1.4.2-cp310-cp310-win32.whl
```

#### Step three

You had successful installed pandas
Check it

```
import pandas
```

Comment: What if we're on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

the problem i had was error on microsoft visiual, mention befor the error of wheel of panda, needed the package of that before install pandas with pip install. now after install the microsoft visiual then use pip install panda and then pip install transform i had no errors.

Comment: Please update your answer to make the issue and solution clearer, and also correct the spelling and grammar. As it is currently written, it is hard to understand. Thanks.