# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dot' : return X.dot(self.W) + self.b

Tags: python, tkinter, linear-regression

I have a problem that I can not get to solve.

I have two classes, class 1 deals with the view, class 2 with the calculation.

Class 1 accesses class 2. In class 1 is an instance of class 2 to access the predict method. The method predict has one argument. I set this argument over the input field in class 1. Then this error always occurs :
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dot' :     return X.dot(self.W) + self.b
Error when i push the button

Class 1:

```
class Example1:
    self.linearregression = LinearRegression(self,None)

    test = tk.DoubleVar(self)
    test.set("1.0")

    self.predictbutton = ttk.Button(self.plotframe, text = "predict", command = lambda:self.linearregression.predict(test.get()))
        self.predictbutton.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Class 2:

```
class LinearRegression():

    def __init__(self, learning_rate, iterations):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.iterations = iterations
    # Function for model training
    def fit(self, X, Y):
        # no_of_training_examples, no_of_features
        self.m, self.n = X.shape
        # weight initialization
        self.W = np.zeros(self.n)
        self.b = 0
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        # gradient descent learning
        for i in range(self.iterations):
            self.update_weights()
        return self

    # Helper function to update weights in gradient descent

    def update_weights(self):
        Y_pred = self.predict(self.X)

        # calculate gradients
        dW = - (2 * (self.X.T).dot(self.Y - Y_pred)) / self.m
        db = - 2 * np.sum(self.Y - Y_pred) / self.m
        # update weights
        self.W = self.W - self.learning_rate * dW
        self.b = self.b - self.learning_rate * db
        return self
    # Hypothetical function  h( x )
    def predict(self, X):
        return X.dot(self.W) + self.b
```

Comment: That error indicates that `X` is a `float` instead of (presumably) a vector.  Maybe you meant to use `self.X` instead?

Comment: No that’s not work :(

Comment: In your button command you pass a floating point number `1.0` why do you expect it to have a attribute `dot`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `predictbutton` calls `predict` with the argument `1.0`. And in the method predict you name the argument `X`. And in the methods body you try to use an attribute `dot` via `X.dot`. Maybe you are looking for `numpy.dot(X, self.W)` but that is just a guess. Also it is pointless to return to a `tk.Button`

Comment: With the help of Linear Regression, I try to enter an X-value to get a Y-value. That is, in my GUI, I have an input field where I enter an X value, which causes me to confirm that value via a button. By confirming, this value should be passed as an argument to the predict method.

The class LinearRegression, I have not written myself, but copied and included in my program.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-regression-implementation-from-scratch-using-python/

Comment: I want to use the input field to simply pass a value(X) to this method so I can get a Y value out of it. I don't understand how to get rid of this error message :(

Comment: In your shared link they don't pass a bare floating point number they use an array returned by [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). I don't see how your program will work without rewriting it.

Comment: When I apply your change, I get this error message @Thingamabobs

Comment: Oh, so my idea with the split link code won't work? If I pass a number through input field of the method @Thingamabobs

Comment: In fact I'm not quite sure what you want to do. Your source takes in a [dataset](https://github.com/mohit-baliyan/references/blob/master/salary_data.csv). How do you expect it to be replaced with a single value or even a value pair? You should try to understand the code you want to use before you try to implement it somewhere else.

Comment: I have trained the model with my data set (30 X-values and 30 Y-values), so the result is a linear function. 

Now, with the help of this function, it is possible to output a Y-value from any X-value. 

I wanted to do this with the help of the input field, that I enter any X-value, press the button "predict" and the corresponding Y-value is output.

Comment: This is not possible with the code as it is. They use [pandas.dataframe.dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas-dataframe-dot) A single value is not an array. You could rewrite your code to pass an appropriated parameter to your function.

Comment: Hm, okay, in that i have no experience:(

Comment: You could start now to gain some or you solve [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72401377/13629335) and I solve your problem. :D

Comment: Interesting problem, but I have no idea xD 

is it difficult to rewrite my code so that I enter an X value and get out the corresponding Y value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247590/discussion-between-thingamabobs-and-deutscherkaffee).