# Issue of installing of pandas in vscode

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, data-science, data-analysis

I have create a sample project and adding environment then try to install pandas it show me this

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas

Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have download this too :- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: How did you create the environment? Which version of Python did you install? Which version of pandas are you trying to install?

Comment: I have Python 3.10.5
I tried with pip install pandas as well as pip install pandas==1.1.5
Environment:- virtualenv myenv  and then setting interpreter

Comment: The latest stable version for Pandas is 1.5.3, try installing that.

Comment: Also, is it Python 3.10.5 32-bit or 64-bit? Pandas does not ship 32-bit wheels for Python 3.10. So you could try using Python 3.9 if you need it to be 32-bit.

Comment: The error message is not complete, so you only have people guessing the problem here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401377/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-pandas-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject)

Comment: @EduardoMottadeMoraes i use 64 bit but somehow i am able to install pandas 1.5.3 as you suggest.