# how do I get the pip install pandas command to work?

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I wanted to install pandas because I needed it in a python script. But when I ran the pip install pandas command, I got the following error:

**Message error :**

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.1.3.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\titouan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2m33b6wv\pandas_d0cbd89973b2444cb852211ba74ff89a C:\Users\titouan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2m33b6wv\pandas_d0cbd89973b2444cb852211ba74ff89a\.mesonpy-1gtwaj3m\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\titouan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2m33b6wv\pandas_d0cbd89973b2444cb852211ba74ff89a\.mesonpy-1gtwaj3m\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\titouan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2m33b6wv\pandas_d0cbd89973b2444cb852211ba74ff89a
      Build dir: C:\Users\titouan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2m33b6wv\pandas_d0cbd89973b2444cb852211ba74ff89a\.mesonpy-1gtwaj3m\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.1.3

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\titouan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2m33b6wv\pandas_d0cbd89973b2444cb852211ba74ff89a\.mesonpy-1gtwaj3m\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

**So I tried to update pip but it didn't change anything. So I'd like to know how to successfully install pandas?**

Regards,

Comment: That **meson-log.txt** file would probably give a better clue as to what went wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401377/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-pandas-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject

Comment: I don't have anything in the directory for the meson-log.txt when i try to find the full log.

Comment: My python version is 3.11.3.